# Is there a Warlock (multiclass Bard) or Tiefling equivalent of Enter The Crucible or StoneSkin?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock

Both of those powers seem to allow you to "tank" 10 of damages, every turn. Our contact fighters have had Enter The Crucible for a while, and our mage just had StoneSkin appear as an option that looks pretty similar on level 16.

My warlock is under equipped thus lacking in defenses in comparison with the others. He's a heavy hitter but he gets hit easily, so I'm seriously considering sacrificing all of the slots of level 16 to **Train Endurance** (which isn't a core warlock skill & needed for this power) and **take Enter The Crucible**, which is a level 10 pwr. Just because I spend a lot of time healing myself in combat, which feels silly.

Is there a Warlock or a Tiefling or a Bard equivalent that wouldn't require me to make a build so weird?

Comment: What're your defender and your leader doing if your *warlock* is taking hits and healing himself?!

Answer (score 1):

#### Resisting damage isn't a big Warlock or Bard thing, but...

The *Red Leeches of Nihal* (Dragon 366) and *Bond of Brotherhood* (Arcane Power) utilities will give you some sustain potential, giving you a second wind worth of temporary HP (leeches) or an equal amount of healing (brotherhood) whenever somebody else spends a healing surge.

Combat-relevant Warlock utilities are more likely to be "bargains" that give you a little vulnerability in exchange for another benefit, like *Troublesome Aid of Caiphon* or *Caiphon's Disquieting Liberty*, and Bard utilities are mostly benefits for the whole party.

Answer (score 0):

Warlock has several strong defensive utilities, even if they don't precisely match what you've mentioned. They tend to be Encounter powers and so limited to one round, but in turn available every combat. For example:

Spectral Fade (U2)- Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdom/Heroes of Shadow, for invisibility for a round.

Iron Aspect of Dispater (U6)- HotFK, minor action for resist 5 all for a round

Mirror Darkly (U6)- Heroes of Shadow- minor action for a shade that can be an origin point for attacks and that makes you insubstantial while you persist

A Tiefling Warlock can take the Warlock's Wrath feat from Dragon 381 to replace Infernal Wrath with a minor action power that gives you +Cha to your defenses and half level + int damage to anyone who attacks you. It also ups your curse damage

Bard has an extremely powerful defensive utility from Arcane Power in Mantle of Unity (U10), which is a minor action, encounter, giving everyone in your party the highest of each defense in the party (eg you could have your mage's Reflex, your Fighter's AC and Constitution, etc)

Answer (score -1):

Utility powers you might want to consider a swap for particularly if you can take them via Secrets of Belial:

Channeling Shield (Swordmage)
Elemental Shield (Sorcerer)
Moonstride (Wizard)
Charm of Protection (Wizard)
Mass Resistance (Wizard)
Revitalizing Incantation (Bard)